# MiKTeX unexpectedly stops; problem with dictionary?

Tags: errors

I just installed the latest MiKTeX on a Windows 10 and installed the latest WinEdt. I have used them before on a different machine (which broke down) quite some time ago. I tried to compile an example file from the web and it worked fine. With my own file, MiKTeX unexpectedly stops. I tried both WinEdt and TeXworks. They return as last lines:

```
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd")
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@argtabularcr [#1]->\ifnum \z@ =`{\fi }
                                        &\omit {\ifnum \z@ =`}\fi \global \a...
l.106 

?
```

But line 106 in my tex file is empty...
The last part of the log file gives

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
(C:\Users\werf025\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/translator\translator-ba
sic-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Lang
```

I have no clue what's going on... I'd be grateful if someone could help, keeping in mind that I'm neither very technical nor very skilled with TeX.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Best regards,
Edwin

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno,a4paper]{article}  

\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add} %if only this line commented away then it works  
\usepackage{tabls} %if only this line commented away then it works  
%if both lines are commented away then it works  
%if both lines are being read then error...  

\begin{document}  
\begin{table}  
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}  

a & b & c & d  & e \\  
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\  

\end{tabular}  
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: line 106 could be in some other file. As your log is incomplete one can't see which file is actually open, but it looks like a problem with some package. Show a complete example.

Comment: tabls is not compatible with the newest array.sty version, so I would say better don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

your problem can be reduced to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabls} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
a & b & c & d  & e \\
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives your error and shows that tabls is not compatible with the newest array.sty version. You could try to contact the author, perhaps he corrects it.